# Activate and Login user after registration Gravity Form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I wanted to automatically activate and login user after registration on my site using gravityform is there a way?

.I did some research and currently some of the guides are outdated.I tried this code,currently its not working

```
     function autologin($user_id, $config, $entry, $password) {

     wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id, false, '');

 }

 add_action("gform_user_registered", "autologin", 10, 4);
```

Comment: Is registration functionality is already there by gravity form or you also wants to add ?

Comment: @Savan I have the registration add on already installed,I just need to register the user progmatically and redirect to homepage on 1 click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
function pi_gravity_registration_autologin( $user_id, $user_config, $entry, $password ) {

    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $user_password = $password;

    wp_signon( array(
        'user_login' => $user_login,
        'user_password' =>  $user_password,
        'remember' => false
    ), false );

    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, false );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );
}
```

Comment: Yes,It doesn't register a user.

Comment: vel I've updated my post.I still can't figure out how to activate the user progmatically.

Comment: you did add this code `wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, false );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user_login );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158574/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-vel).

Answer (score 2):

This checks if the user is logged in or not.  If not, they will auto-login upon form submission.

```
/**
* Auto login after registration if not logged in.
*/
function ip_gravity_registration_autologin( $user_id, $user_config, $entry, $password ) {
    // Only automatically login if we aren't *already* logged in
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // Get the user data (for the login)
        $user = get_userdata( $user_id );
        // Sign the user in
        wp_signon( array(
            'user_login' => $user->user_login,
            'user_password' => $password,
            'remember' => false, // Don't set the remember cookie
        ));
    }
}
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'ip_gravity_registration_autologin', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the code from my [Gravity Forms Auto Login](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-auto-login/) plugin that handles this.

```
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'gw_auto_login', 10, 4 );
function gw_auto_login( $user_id, $feed, $entry, $password ) {

    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_data = array(
        'user_login'     => $user->user_login,
        'user_password'    => $password,
        'remember'        => false
    );

    $result = wp_signon( $user_data );

    if( ! is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        global $current_user;
        $current_user = $result;
    }

}
```

The plugin accounts for many other Gravity Forms scenarios that might interfere with automatically logging the user in.

Comment: Thanks but where does it check for already logged in condition? Is `! is_wp_error` part of it?